# How to write xml in asset folder

Tags: java, android, xml

I want to write below text in xml tag. I have tried but it says the xml is not in well formated .

```
<QUESTIONS>public class xyz {
   public static void main(String args[]) {
      for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
         for(int j = 2; j>= 0; j--) {
            if(i == j) break;
            System.out.println("i=" + i + " j="+j);
         }
      }
   }
}</QUESTIONS>
```

Comment: You can't write into the assets folder. Only in the sd. Also mind that you wrote **Java code** into an xml file, which is a terrible idea. Also note that the tag <questions /> is **not well formed**, since it's ALL UPPER CASE (while the w3c xhtml specs say it should be all lower case)

Comment: Not true; see below.  Case has nothing to do with being well formed.  Upper, lower, and camel case are allowed for tag names.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `cdata` tags to make your xml valid.

```
<QUESTIONS>
<![CDATA[
public class xyz {
   public static void main(String args[]) {
      for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
         for(int j = 2; j>= 0; j--) {
            if(i == j) break;
            System.out.println("i=" + i + " j="+j);
         }
      }
   }
}
]]>
</QUESTIONS>
```

Comment: it's not display anything .The android screen is blank.

Comment: You didn't say how you would be using them. If you want help implementing this, you should update your first post and show us the code you are using.

Comment: means i want to say i have used your code line but when i run the app this syntax public class xyz {
   public static void main(String args[]) {
      for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
         for(int j = 2; j>= 0; j--) {
            if(i == j) break;
            System.out.println("i=" + i + " j="+j);
         }
      }
   }
} is not display in textview.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a terrible idea, but here's how you can make it work if you must:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<QUESTIONS>
<![CDATA[
public class xyz {
   public static void main(String args[]) {
      for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
         for(int j = 2; j>= 0; j--) {
            if(i == j) break;
            System.out.println("i=" + i + " j="+j);
         }
      }
   }
}
]]>
</QUESTIONS>
```

This makes your XML valid according any parser, but that won't fix any issues you have with consuming it.

You realize, of course, that this introduces a new element into the DOM tree.  You might have coded this so you'd get the text child of the QUESTIONS element; now you'll have to get it from the CDATA child of the QUESTIONS element.